# Pod release failed

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podspec, run-script

I'm developing a Pod.

I've 2 files(*json and yml*) in (Example)project's root folder(not in pod itself).

I've written a Run-Script in the Pod's **.podSpec** file using `script_phases` to copy the contents of JSON file into the YML file `before_compile`.

File paths: `../../file.json` and `../../file.yml` defined in the .podSpec file, which points to the project's root folder.

It's working fine locally. But when I try to release the Pod using Jenkins, it says: `No such file or directory: file.json`.

Do we need to have both the files to be included inside the pod itself to release the pod, means we cannot create run script when the pod doesn't have the files inside it?

Answer (score 0):

Right. The podspec needs to specify all the files that need to be distributed.

Comment: What might be the reason?

Comment: The podspec determines what gets loaded from the `s.source` repo into the Pod installation. `Development Pods` don't enforce that restriction.